# Swiper overflows inside grid with Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, microsoft-edge, swiper.js

[This Swiper Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topsu/5hg2x6dc/11/) works with Firefox and Chrome. Apparently my grid layout breaks this with Edge and Safari (without `display: grid` this fiddle will work with Safari and Edge). However, I don't want to replace the grid with flexbox.

How can I get this working in Edge and Safari while using `display: grid`?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 8fr 4fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>



</head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <div>
          <p>
            Vivamus placerat lacus vel vehicula scelerisque, dui enim adipiscing lacus sit amet sagittis, libero enim vitae mi. In neque magna posuere, euismod ac tincidunt tempor est. Ut suscipit nisi eu purus. Proin ut pede mauris eget ipsum. Integer vel quam nunc commodo consequat. Integer ac eros eu tellus dignissim viverra. Maecenas erat aliquam erat volutpat. Ut venenatis ipsum quis turpis. Integer cursus scelerisque lorem. Sed nec mauris id quam blandit consequat. Cras nibh mi hendrerit vitae, dapibus et aliquam et magna. Nulla vitae elit. Mauris consectetuer odio vitae augue.
          </p>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a issue in using flexible unit (`fr`), and Safari isn't calculating the width correctly. A workaround for this issue is to define grid columns with `minmax()`, for example `grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 8fr) 4fr;`

Comment: you are the best :)